# How to change back to keyboard input in Genshin Impact when controller turned off

Tags: genshin-impact

I play Genshin Impact with a controller and to quit a game, you have to reach the so called Paimon menu.

However, when I pause the game and the controller battery is off, I only get a the following message:

[image]

Every game detects if I move the controller or the mouse and adjusts the input accordingly.

So, basically I should change to another input (or restart a game) *without* the game detecting the available input??? How?

**EDIT:**

Some fun fact: they couldn't fix a 3 years old bug of [disconnection of the controller](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/j28c81/anyone_else_having_strange_controller_connection/?rdt=48213)...it can't connect back until the game is force closed. I would say that is a poor design... I probably return to some decent western RPGs

Answer (score 2):

Genshin Impact does not supports switching back to Keyboard and Mouse once the game has been manually set to Controller mode. As the text says, you need to restart the game to switch back.

This is also pointed out in the [PCGW Article for Genshin Impact](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Genshin_Impact#Input):

[image]

Comment: But how do I restart the game if I need the controller to exit it? I can't reach the menu as the controller is off and the mouse is not working....

Comment: The game expects a Keyboard and Mouse sadly.

Comment: So they admit that a requirement every game since 2001 can provide, is not possible to be addressed in Genshin? That's very embarassing. So what's the solution? Task Manager? :D

Comment: Yeah, Task Manager is the only solution. I had this happen with a DualShock 4.

Comment: "a requirement every game since 2001 can provide" [The Metal Gear Solid Collection](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2131630) is going to be released in 9 days and does not supports mouse and keyboard at all, so there are a lot of lazy companies doing this xd

Comment: Astonishing :O I didn't know that JRPG games are so much behind European and American games...thanks for giving some elaboration on the subject.